# Magento not displaying SSL references in view source

Tags: magento, ssl

When setting up the Magento back end to 'Use SSL on Frontend' and setting the unsecured url and secured url to https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/shop, if I view source Magento is not displaying the references with https:// thus giving insecure content warnings..

I'm at a loss to why this is happening.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/shop/skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/shop/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/shop/skin/frontend/default/default/css/sidenav.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/shop/skin/frontend/default/default/css/sidenavcollapse.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/shop/skin/frontend/default/default/css/webtex/bubble.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/shop/skin/frontend/default/default/css/print.css" media="print" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/shop/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/shop/js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/shop/js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/shop/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/shop/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/shop/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/shop/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Come to find out the server was not configured to share sessions correctly between http and https all is working now. i would 'answer' my question but I don't have 10 rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

After making configuration changes, you must clear your Magento cache so Magento is using the correct values.

Go to `System > Cache Management`, check all of the cache types and refresh.

Comment: I guess I should have included that in the question, I have cleared all cache types.

Comment: What values do you have in `Base Link URL`, `Base Skin URL`, `Base Media URL` and `Base JavaScript URL`?

Comment: the server was not configured to share sessions correctly between http and https all is working now. I would 'answer' my question but I don't have 10 rep yet, thanks for the feedback though!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else coming across this should also beware that Magento will only set https as source for loaded resources when https is actually 'needed', i.e when you browse the cart, checkout or account pages.

Ref:

1. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/896/https-layout-broken
2. http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/magento-https-redirect-loop/